# Why does systemd-networkd consider UseDomains= (domain search list from DHCP) less safe than LLMNR?

Tags: systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

> UseDomains=
>
> Takes a boolean argument, or the special value "route". When true, the domain name received from the DHCP server will be used as DNS
>   search domain over this link, similar to the effect of the Domains=
>   setting. If set to "route", the domain name received from the DHCP
>   server will be used for routing DNS queries only, but not for
>   searching, similar to the effect of the Domains= setting when the
>   argument is prefixed with "~". Defaults to false.
>
> It is recommended to enable this option only on trusted networks, as setting this affects resolution of all host names, in particular of
>   single-label names. It is generally safer to use the supplied domain
>   only as routing domain, rather than as search domain, in order to not
>   have it affect local resolution of single-label names.

compare

> LLMNR=
>
> A boolean or "resolve". When true, enables Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution on the link. When set to "resolve", only resolution is
>   enabled, but not host registration and announcement. Defaults to true.

but LLMNR also resolves single-label names. Can anyone explain this?

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html as of systemd version 239.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a justification posted in 2015.
https://www.mail-archive.com/systemd-devel@lists.freedesktop.org/msg31563.html

> > iiuc, the concern was that multi-level domain names (i.e. those with at least
> >     one dot) could be spoofed by controlling the search suffix. But for
> >     names with at least two levels glibc only uses the search list as a
> >     fallback.
>
> Well, sure, being able to influence things at the beginning of the
>   search logic is more problematic than influencing things at the end of
>   the search logic, but i still think it's problematic, since it still
>   allows you to insert "home.foobar.com" into a domain "foobar.com" that
>   doesn't have "home.foobar.com" itself but only "www.bar.com"...
>
> Sure, classic (non-DNSSEC) DNS is not ever going to be fully secure,
>   but it I still believe we should default to the safer options, and
>   allow the others.
>
> Altering the search paths is inherently something that makes no sense
>   on public networks, it only makes sense if you know your network well,
>   and trust it to some level. Hence opt-in sounds like the better option
>   to me.